# Change font color based on a condition in HTML

Tags: html, fonts, background-color

I want to change the colour of some text on the body of outlook depending on input from a python script. Basically I have a variable, "Test_Status" and it should display text in a certain colour as per condition below.
If Test_status is blocked, display text in Orange
If Test_status is passed, display text in Green
If Test_status is failed, display text in Red

Request to help me out on this...

[Html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpCqL.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

The following code works:

```
if Test_Status == "blocked":
   color = "orange"
elif Test_Status = "passed":
   color = "green"
elif Test_Status = "failed":
   color = "red"
```

Inside the body tag, add the following code:

```
''' + f"<p style='color: {color_1}'>State of Task: {Test_Status}</p>" + ''' <br><br>
```